# How to consolidate the results of Mono Objects in spring WebFlux?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

Please look at the below code from controller(Added comments) which uses RestTemplate:

```
@GetMapping("/{courseid}")
public Course getCourseDetails(@PathVariable Long courseid) {

    // Get Course info (ID, Name, Description) from pre-populated Array List
    CourseInfo courseInfo = getCourseInfo(courseid);
    
    // Get Price info of a course from another microservice using RESTTemplate
    Price price = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8002/price/"+courseid, Price.class);
    
    // Get enrollment info of a course from another microservice using RESTTemplate
    Enrollment enrollment = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8003/enrollment/"+courseid, Enrollment.class);
    
    //Consolidate everything in to Course object and send it as response
    return new Course(courseInfo.getCourseID(), courseInfo.getCourseName(), courseInfo.getCourseDesc(), price.getDiscountedPrice(),
            enrollment.getEnrollmentOpen());
}
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same using Reactive programming. I now use WebClient and Mono from Web-Flux. But, I am so confused as to how to combine the results? Take a look at the below code (Just using Mono Everywhere. Rest of the code remained same)

```
@GetMapping("/{courseid}")
public Mono<Course> getCourseDetails(@PathVariable Long courseid) {

    // Get Course info (ID, Name, Description) from pre-populated Array List
    CourseInfo courseInfo = getCourseInfo(courseid);
    
    // Get Price info of a course from another microservice using RESTTemplate
    Mono<Price> price = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8002/price/{courseid}/",courseid).retrieve().bodyToMono(Price.class);
    
    // Get enrollment info of a course from another microservice using RESTTemplate
    Mono<Enrollment> inventory = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8003/enrollment/{courseid}/",courseid).retrieve().bodyToMono(Enrollment.class);
    
    //Question : How do we Consolidate everything and form a Mono<Course> object and send it as response?
    
}
```

Question 1 : How do we Consolidate everything and form a Mono object and send it as response?

Question 2 : Does the statement "CourseInfo courseInfo = getCourseInfo(courseid);" cause blocking operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to:

> Question 1 : How do we Consolidate everything and form a Mono object and send it as response?

**Mono.zip(..)** is what you need to combine the two results. This diagram is from the [doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) :

[image: zip doc]

Note that, `zip` will result in an **empty Mono** if one of A or 1 is empty! Use `switchIfEmpty`/`defaultIfEmpty` to protect against that case.

Thus the code looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/{courseid}")
public Mono<Course> getCourseDetails(@PathVariable Long courseid) {

    CourseInfo courseInfo = getCourseInfo(courseid);
    Mono<Price> priceMono = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8002/price/{courseid}/",courseid).retrieve().bodyToMono(Price.class);
    Mono<Enrollment> enrollmentMono = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8003/enrollment/{courseid}/",courseid).retrieve().bodyToMono(Enrollment.class);
    
    return Mono.zip(priceMono, enrollmentMono).map(t -> new Course(courseInfo.getCourseID(), courseInfo.getCourseName(), courseInfo.getCourseDesc(), t.getT1().getDiscountedPrice(),
            t.getT2().getEnrollmentOpen()));
    
}
```

Now answering to:

> Question 2 : Does the statement "CourseInfo courseInfo = getCourseInfo(courseid);" cause blocking operation?

Since you mentioned that `Get Course info (ID, Name, Description) from pre-populated Array List`, **if it is just an in-memory Array containing the course information, then it's not blocking**.

But (as @mslowiak also mentioned), **if `getCourseInfo` contains logic which involves querying a database, ensure that you are not using a blocking JDBC driver. If so, then there is no point of using Webflux and Reactor.** Use [Spring R2DBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference) if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you! That answers. Also, do you know how can we be sure, that there are no blocking operations, while using reactive programming?

Comment: @rakeshmehra well, there is no such fixed rule. You can google up for that. or find it intuitively. eg You can check that the underlying implementation of the JDBC driver is a blocking one  because it has no reference of Flux/Mono anywhere in it's classes. i.e it is not using Reactor. The only 2 reactive projects in Java are RxJava and Reactor

Comment: In large project with hundreds of microbreweries, even if you have one blocking operation somewhere, it might defeat the purpose of reactive programming. I believe it's difficult to find blocking operations manually. But, there seem to be a Library that detects blocking operations.

Comment: First of all, you cant call a blocking method when using Spring Webflux. It throws error. You can try it out. So it wont work with the old jdbc driver too. I donno if you mean microservices , when you said microbreweries. When a call is going to a different microservice, you dont have to worry about that being reactive or not.

Comment: Yes, Accepted as solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. `restTemplate.getForObject` returns simple object - in your case `Price` or `Enrollment`. To convert them to Mono you can simply `Mono.just(object)`, however better solution would be to switch to [Webclient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) which is default HTTP client for Spring Reactive
2. `getCourseInfo` it depends what is the logic behind this method. For sure if there is a JDBC connection behind that method it is blocking.
3. To make a final response with `Mono<Course>` you should think about [zip operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-) which will help you with that.

For ex:

```
Mono<Course> courseMono = Mono.zip(price, enrollment)
        .map(tuple -> new Course(courseInfo, tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));
```

Comment: I meant to use WebClient(I've corrected the question). But, the last statement doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I just realized "t.getT1()" Supposed to be "t.getT1().getDiscountedPrice()" and it works!